# Dynamically loaded user control's button click event is not fired

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ascx

I have web application built using jQuery, ASP.NET, VB.NET. This application has tabs built using jQuery tabs. On a click of a tab, a user control is loaded into a div dynamically as follows.

```
    //Load user control - jquery call to page method to load user control
LoadTabControlPage = function (tabselected) {
    var loc = window.location.href;
    loc = (loc.substr(loc.length - 1, 1) == "/") ? loc + "Default.aspx" : loc;
    $j.ajax({
        url: loc + "/Result",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: '{ "controlName": "' + tabselected + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        statusCode: {
            200: function (response) {
                $j('#controlsdiv').show();
                $j('#controlsdiv').html(response.d);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

PageMethod in VB:

```
    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function Result(controlName As String) As String
       Dim page As New UI.Page()
       Dim userControl As UserControl = DirectCast(page.LoadControl("UI/" + controlName.Replace(" ", "") + ".ascx"), UserControl)
       userControl.EnableViewState = False
       Dim form As New HtmlForm()
       form.Controls.Add(userControl)
       page.Controls.Add(form)

       Dim textWriter As New StringWriter()
       HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, textWriter, False)
       Return textWriter.ToString()
    End Function
```

Issue is after loading a user control, its button event isn't getting fired.
MyAscx file:

```
    <asp:Button ID="reportsbtn" Text="Run Report" OnClick="reportsbtn_Click" runat="server" />
```

MYAscx.vb

```
    Protected Sub reportsbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles reportsbtn.Click        
        //Code            
    End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think control created in such way (it's HTML simple funneled to the page via jQuery Ajax call) would participate in page lifecycle (including button clicks)

Comment: Thanks. I think you're right. I needed this only for one control. So I used a div to hide and show for this particular tab instead of loading a new user control.